LTSpice Unknown SPICE device type "N"
I try to use the model for the BFR106 transistor in LTSpice, which I got from here
https://www.infineon.com/cms/en/product/rf/rf-transistor/high-linearity-rf-transistors/bfr106/?tab=~%27simulation_models#!designsupport
, and it gives me an error saying "Unknown SPICE device type N". I take the npn symbol and I make the prefix "NPN" and the value "M_BFR106". I use the .inc spice directive and specify the path where the BFR106.mdl is located. I think the problem is that it's encrypted or it's not in the right format (probably the latter).
BFR106.mdl
***************************************************************
*   Infineon    Technologies    AG
*   GUMMEL-POON MODEL   IN  SPICE   2G6 SYNTAX
*   VALID   UP  TO  6   GHZ
*   >>> BFR106  <<<
*   (C) 2012    Infineon    Technologies    AG
*   Version 2.1 January 2012
***************************************************************
* - Please use the global SPICE GP parameter TEMP to specify the
*   junction temperature of the device in your application to get
*   correct simulation results. This procedure is necessary because
*   the GP model does not consider the self heating of the device.
* - TEMP is calculated by TEMP=TA+Pdc*(RthJS+RthSA). The junction
*   temperature TEMP is the sum of the ambient temperature TA and
*   the increment of temperature caused by the dissipated DC power Pdc.
* - RthJS is the thermal resistance between the junction and the
*   soldering point. RthJS for this device is 110 K/W. RthSA is the
*   thermal resistance of the PCB, from the soldering point to the
*   ambient. For determination of RthSA please refer to Infineon's
*   Application Note "Thermal Resistance Calculation" AN077.
* - The model has been verified in the junction temperature range
*   -25ï¿½C to +125ï¿½C.
* - TNOM=25 ï¿½C is the nominal ambient temperature during measurement
*   for the parameter extraction. Please do not change this value.
****************************************************************
*.OPTION TNOM=25, GMIN= 1.00e-12
*BFR106 C B E
.SUBCKT BFR106 1 2 3
*
CBEPAR 22 33 2.22E-012
CBCPAR 22 11 4.288E-013
CCEPAR 11  33 2.621E-015
LB    22 20 6.736E-010
LE   33 30 6.937E-010
CBEPCK 20 30  1.567E-014
CBCPCK 11 20  1.975E-013
CCEPCK 11 30  1.497E-013
LBX    20 2 7.342E-010
LEX   30 3 6.492E-010
LCX   11 1  6.908E-010
*
Q1 11 22 33  M_BFR106
*
.MODEL  M_BFR106    NPN(
+   TNOM = 25
+   IS  =   1.779E-015
+   BF  =   113.8
+   NF  =   1
+   VAF =   27.87
+   IKF =   1.181
+   ISE =   1.644E-014
+   NE  =   2
+   BR  =   22
+   NR  =   0.9964
+   VAR =   3.898
+   IKR =   0.1065
+   ISC =   8.839E-014
+   NC  =   1.567
+   RB  =   4.5
+   IRB =   0
+   RBM =   2.5
+   RE  =   0.07303
+   RC  =   5.1
+   XTB =   1.303
+   EG  =   1.12
+   XTI =   6.548
+   CJE =   4.149E-012
+   VJE =   0.8551
+   MJE =   0.4611
+   TF  =   2.345E-011
+   XTF =   10.29
+   VTF =   7.452
+   ITF =   0.5446
+   PTF =   0.08058
+   CJC =   9.627E-013
+   VJC =   0.5893
+   MJC =   0.4818
+   XCJC    =   0.5631
+   TR  =   1.434E-010
+   CJS =   0
+   VJS =   1
+   MJS =   1
+   FC  =   0.5
+   KF  =   8.22E-015
+   AF  =   1.51)
***************************************************************
*
.ENDS BFR106

I'd appreciate it if someone can tell me how to fix this, or to teach me how to create the .MODEL from scratch and what parameters I need to specify.

Place the model you are using in text in your question. You can use the "code" feature to make it list out nicely, too. Also, if possible, in a separate code block put your netlist that you can get from LTspice.

Please post a screenshot of the spice model as well as code

Don't change the prefix.  The prefix should remain as QN.  However, you shouldn't be using just the .model with a symbol, you should be using the whole subcircuit for RF transistors.  See the posted answer and also this article if you want to use the NPN symbol.  https://www.analog.com/en/resources/technical-articles/ltspice-using-an-intrinsic-symbol-for-a-third-party-model.html

It is a library containing several transistors.
Open the .lib in LTspice. Scroll to the line that shows .subckt bfr106, rightclick on .subckt and choose "Create Symbol".
Use that symbol in your schematic.
Connect the pins as described in the .lib file:
*BFR106 C B E
.SUBCKT BFR106 1 2 3

